# Подсчитать наибольшее количество идущих подряд цифр (С++)

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно подсчитать наибольшее кол-во цифр в задаваемом тексте. Думаю делать так: проверять каждый символ на то, цифра ли это, подсчитать цифры до символа-не цифры, записывая максимальное полученное кол-во в отдельную переменную и перезаписывать её каждый раз, когда найдётся большее количество, в конце вывести эту переменную как результат. Написал нижеследующую программу, но выдаёт ошибку lvalue required as left operand of assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
    string a;
    int i, x = 0, xmax = 0;
    cout << "Введите предложение: " << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    for (i=0; i < a.npos; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]='1' or a[i]='2' or a[i]='3' or a[i]='4' or a[i]='5' or a[i]='6' or a[i]='7' or a[i]='8' or a[i]='9' or a[i]='0')
        {
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
            x=0;
        }
        if (x>xmax)
        {
            xmax=x;
        }
    }
    cout << "Наибольшее кол-во чисел, идущих подряд: " << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++ логическое или реализовано как "||", а логическое и как "&&". Также вопрос, зачем использовать npos, если можно использовать lenght? Если углубиться в неявные преобразования типов, то можно вспомнить, что символ можно представить и в числовом эквиваленте. И наконец, вместо x нужно вывести xmax, так как x является промежуточной переменной

Наиболее удачным решением будет следующее

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    string a;
    int x = 0, xmax = 0;
    cout << "Введите предложение: " << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (a[i] >= '0' && a[i] <= '9') {
            x++;
        }
        else {
            x = 0;
        }
        if (x > xmax) {
            xmax = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "Наибольшее кол-во чисел, идущих подряд: " << xmax << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: №1. количество и размер строки имеют без знаковый тип,  №2  не верное сравнение  code > 0 && code < 9, нужно    **code >= 0 && code <= 9**  №3. числовое представление символов тут ни к чему. Можно просто символы сравнивать :   **a[i] <= '9' && a[i] >= '0'**

Comment: @ARHovsepyan По поводу первого замечания вас не совсем понял, а другие 2 недочёта подправлю.

Comment: ну  тип int замените на unsigned,  а лучше на size_t. 
Например в цикле,, при сравнении  i < a.length() (последний скорее вернет size_t),  с типом int для 64 битного приложения вы наверняка получите предупреждение о возможном переполнении int. Всегда лучше использовать соответствующие типы _ они сами по себе "говорят" о ваших намерениях...